# Why does my app crash when I try to access it's intent data?

Tags: java, android, image, crash, thumbnails

I'm developing an android application it keeps crashing when i press a button to take a photo, which then should save the picture to a folder and display a thumbnail in the application, however once i take a photo, the app crashes, nevertheless saves the photo in the desired folder. Displaying the thumbnails worked before I started implementing the photo saving part of the app.

**The app crashes once it gets to this block of code (onActivityResult overridden function):**

```
        if(data.getData() == null) {
            thumbnail.add((Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data"));
        }
        if(thumbnail.get(0) != null && thumbnail.size() > 0)
        {
            for(int i=0; i < thumbnail.size();i++){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(thumbnail.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                createPhotoThumbnail(thumbnail);
            }
        }
```

**This is the camera dispatch intent function:**

```
private void dispatchCameraIntent(){
    Intent takePicIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePicIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the Files
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not create file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);

            takePicIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            takePicIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, "720000");
            startActivityForResult(takePicIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, takePicIntent);
        }
    } else
    {
        //Make a toast if there is no camera app installed.
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"No program to take pictures",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

**I've added the logcat:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: lt.vilniausbaldai.vilniausbaldaiofflinedefektai, PID: 14330
 Theme: themes:{}
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {lt.vilniausbaldai.vilniausbaldaiofflinedefektai/lt.vilniausbaldai.vilniausbaldaiofflinedefektai.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3733)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3776)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
  Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
     at lt.vilniausbaldai.vilniausbaldaiofflinedefektai.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:135)
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6456)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3729)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3776) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

**createPhotoThumbnail method:**

```
private void createPhotoThumbnail(ArrayList<Bitmap> thumbnail){
    this.imageGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    this.bitmapList = new ArrayList<>();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < thumbnail.size(); i++) {
            thumbnail.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

            this.bitmapList.add(thumbnail.get(i));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.imageGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, this.bitmapList));
    imageGrid.invalidate();
}
```

**createImageFile method:**

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss").format(new Date());
    //String timeStamp = "picTesting";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            timeStamp,  /* prefix */
            ".png",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    //Toast.makeText(this, mCurrentPhotoPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: please show your stacktrace

Comment: Have you added the permissions ?

Comment: Yes, i've added android.permission.CAMERA and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, I've also included <uses-feature android.hardware.camera.

Answer (score 0):

The error occures quite possibly at this line:

```
if(thumbnail.get(0) != null && thumbnail.size() > 0)
```

This is, because first you try to get the element at index 0 an after that you check if there are even some elements.

If you change the order of those conditions, it should work fine:

```
if(thumbnail.size() > 0 && thumbnail.get(0) != null)
```

With this, you check first if there are even some elements, and only if there are, you try to get the element at index 0 and check it if its `null`.

Comment: Sadly, this did not solve the issue, the app still crashes after saving the photo. It also crashes if it goes through this if: "if(data.getData() == null) {"

Comment: Did you get the same logcat as before?

Comment: The logcat is identical, I even tried both again to make sure.

Comment: So, which line is your `MainActivity:135`?

Comment: 134 refers to createPhotoThumbnail(thumbnail), 135 is the closing curly brace }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    if(data != null){    
         Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultcode == RESULT_OK ){

          if (extras.containsKey("data")) {
                  bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                  thumbnail.add(bitmap);
                }
                if(thumbnail.get(0) != null && thumbnail.size() > 0)
                {
                    for(int i=0; i < thumbnail.size();i++){
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(thumbnail.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        createPhotoThumbnail(thumbnail);
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to prevent the app from crashing, the photo still gets saved, however the whole block of code that adds the thumbnail never gets run, the app never gets past "if(data != null) {"

Comment: Check whether your data is null or not

Comment: i did, data is null.

Comment: Show us where you instantiate `takePicIntent `